# Python - Fetch URL, parse and print PDF

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, reportlab

I'm trying to fetch the HTML source of a URL, parse it and then print the result as PDF.

For that I wanted to rely on BeautifulSoup, urllib2 and reportlab but I lack on how to combine them properly.

As an error I get `'module' object is not callable` when running the django 1.3.1 dev server and accessing the view.

This is my code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from cStringIO import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
# Fetching the URL
import urllib2

# Parsing the HTML
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# The ConverterForm
from django import forms

class ConverterForm(forms.Form):
    # Use textarea instead the default TextInput.
    html_files = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    filename = forms.CharField()

# Create your views here.
def create_pdf(request):
    # If the form has been submitted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A form bound to the POST data
        form = ConverterForm(request.POST)
    # All validation rules pass
    if form.is_valid():
        # PDF creation process
        # Assign variables
        html_files = form.cleaned_data['html_files']
        filename = form.cleaned_data['filename']

        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        # The use of attachment forces the Save as dialog to open.
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % filename

        buffer = StringIO()

        # Get the page source
        page = urllib2.urlopen(html_files)
        html = page.read()

        # Parse the page source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        # Create the PDF object, using the StringIO() object as its "file".
        p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

        # Draw things on the PDF and generate the PDF.
        # See ReportLab documentation for full list of functions.
        p.drawString(100, 100, soup)

        # Close the PDF object cleanly.
        p.showPage()
        p.save()

        # Get the value of the StringIO buffer and write it to the response.
        pdf = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        response.write(pdf)
        return response

    else:
        # An unbound form
        form = ConverterForm()

    # For RequestContext in relation to csrf see more here:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial04/
    return render_to_response('converter/index.html', {
    'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Please show it in full. You have not even shown your whole code.

Comment: I edited the code. Sorry, initially I thought the rest might not be relevant. Regards

Comment: Your exact error is `buffer = StringIO()`, this should be `buffer = StringIO.StringIO()`, but I have provided a simpler solution as an answer.

Comment: I took the buffer part from the django documentation. When using your method I get the error `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'StringIO'`.

Comment: @burhan: `StringIO` is fine. There is `from cStringIO import StringIO` import.

Comment: Ah yeah I missed that import. Thanks Sebastian.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import `BeautifulSoup` class:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

It might be confusing because both the module and the class have the same base name.

Comment: Apparently not on my system. `Could not import converter.views. Error was: No module named BeutifulSoup`. I use the ActivePython distribution and installed beautifulsoup through pypm.

http://code.activestate.com/pypm/beautifulsoup/

Comment: @orschiro: check the spelling.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I updated the code above. The exact error output: http://dpaste.com/721558/

Comment: @orschiro: it solves `'module' object is not callable` problem. There could be many other errors in your code. Update your question or create a new one and paste the full traceback. `p.drawString(100, 100, unicode(soup))` might help with the last error if `p.drawString()` expects `(int, int, unicode)` arguments.

Comment: With `unicode(soup)` it's at least possible to return a pdf file. However, the content of the pdf is plain html and not parsed. Again this is the whole code: http://dpaste.com/721666/

Could it be that BeautifulSoup is not called at all?

Comment: @orschiro: `unicode(soup)` should return plain html. Try to open an interactive Python interpreter and experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way:

```
import cStringIO as StringIO

import ho.pisa as pisa
import requests

def pdf_maker(request):

    browser = requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
    html = browser.text

    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    source = StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('UTF-8')) # adjust as required

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(source,dest=result)

    if not pdf.err:
        response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(),mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=the_file.pdf'
        return response

    return render(request,'error.html')
```

This uses [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) and [pisa](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa). However, you will have some limitations with this (and other such solutions). Namely, you will need to find a way to fetch and embed images yourself, as the PDF conversion process cannot load images directly from the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. But according to PyPi Pisa is not developed any more. Does the XHTML2PDF library behave the same way like Pisa?

Comment: Yes, almost exactly the same way.

Comment: Nonetheless I want to understand why my approach above fails.